# Why does SSRS report take longer to run from report server than Visual Studio?

Tags: sql, performance, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

My report takes about 45 mins to run from visual studio and 1 min 36 sec from report server.

Any idea why does this happen and how can I avoid this?

Thanks,
AR

Comment: Maybe the report server is handling more traffic than your local box.

Comment: it could be a host of issues causing this. Your machine resources if you are running it locally, your network bandwidth if there is a lot of data transfer...etc. looking at prefmon and possibly running a trace of the stored proc could give you some insight. Also 1min 36 seconds is still a very long time for an rdl to render.